# display each category with their items from table in select option

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I've one table **products_tbl**

```
+----------+-----------+---------------+
|product_id|ProductName|ProductCategory|
+----------+-----------+---------------+
|1         |Apple      |fruits         |
|2         |Orange     |fruits         |
|3         |Iphone X   |Electronics    |
|4         |FJ-Eye Lens|Accessories    |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
```

i want to display each categories items in separated group using **HTML SELECT OPTION**

**products.php**

```
$productQ = "SELECT * FROM products_tbl ";
try { 
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare($productQ); 
    $stmt2->execute();
} catch(PDOException $ex) {   
    die("Failed to run Query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

$produtsrows = $stmt2->fetchAll(); 

echo"<select>";
foreach($produtsrows as $prow): 
    echo "<optgroup label=".$prow['ProductCategory'].">";
    echo"   <option>".$prow['ProductName']."</option>
          </optgroup>";
endforeach;
echo "
    </select>
    ";
```

it display it like so

```
fruits
Apple 
fruits
Orange  
Electronics    
Iphone X
Accessories    
FJ-Eye Lens
```

Comment: i want to display all items under one separated category without repeating of category name like it showing to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your foreach loop to not output the category name when it is the same as the last one:

```
$last_cat = "";
foreach($produtsrows as $prow): 
    if (($cat = $prow['ProductCategory']) != $last_cat) {
        if ($last_cat != "") echo "</optgroup>\n";
        echo '<optgroup label="'.$cat.'">' . "\n";
        $last_cat = $cat;
    }
    echo"   <option>".$prow['ProductName']."</option>\n";
endforeach;
echo "</optgroup>\n";
```

Output (for your data)

```
<optgroup label="fruits">
   <option>Apple</option>
   <option>Orange</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Electronics">
   <option>Iphone X</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Accessories">
   <option>FJ-Eye Lens</option>
</optgroup>
```

Comment: its worked perfect as i want , thanks for help , marked as Accepted

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little bit:

```
$productQ = "SELECT * FROM products_tbl ORDER BY ProductCategory ASC";
try { 
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare($productQ); 
    $stmt2->execute();
} catch(PDOException $ex) {   
    die("Failed to run Query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

$produtsrows = $stmt2->fetchAll(); 

echo"<select>";
$category = "";
foreach($produtsrows as $prow): 
    if ($category != $prow['ProductCategory']) {
        if ($category != "") {
            echo "</optgroup>";
        }
        $category = $prow['ProductCategory'];
        echo "<optgroup label=".$prow['ProductName'].">";
    }
    echo"   <option>".$prow['ProductName']."</option>
endforeach;
echo "</optgroup>
    </select>
    ";
```

First note that I added `ORDER BY ProductCategory ASC` to be sure that all products with same category are always together.

Next I Add the `<optgroup>` label only when the category is different from the previous item.

Note that I am assuming all products have a valid category. If you have empty categories the resulting html will be messed up.

Comment: its worked but its only display the categories without their items

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in my code. I already edited for it to work